# Firebird 2.5. Windows 8.1. Can't connect to any database! Why?

Tags: installation, firebird, windows-8

I'm trying to use a FireBird database engine.

OS: Windows 8.1 x64(SmartScreen enabled, UAC enabled, Custom AntiVirus installed(with firewall))

FireBird: Version 2.5, Installed as SuperServer, as application without guardian.

I'm trying to manage this engine using many applications, such as FlameRobin or FireBird Maestro.

At the first:
After installation db said, that the "firebird.msg" not found in windows directory, when I tried retrieve server version.

Ok. I'm copied it to system directory from program files.

At the second(fatal):
I cant connect to my databases!

Firebird Maestro said, when I'm trying connect to created database:
[image]

Or FlameRobin(choosed context menu "Retrieve server version" for "localhost"):
[image]

I'm nothing changed. Never installed firebird database.
Default user(SYSDBA) and password(masterkey) is used, tried in any сase sensitivity.

Today, I'm tried install FireBird on Windows Server 2003, and do some in FlameRobin, and all is works!

Whay the DB not works under Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start Firebird as an application, then Firebird must either be located in a normal folder (not a system folder under UAC protection like `Program Files`), or you need to run it as Administrator.

The reason is that Firebird needs write access to several files in its own program folder, which doesn't work without privilege elevation.

Better yet: run it as a service. The service by default has sufficient rights to start Firebird.

Comment: Mark, is this true for *all* firebird versions (even 3.0)?

Comment: @Wolf Yes, this also applies to Firebird 3.0, the most notable file this applies to is the security database

Comment: ...and this file, I expect, will keep there?

Comment: @Wolf The default location of the security database is in the Firebird installation location, it can be configured elsewhere though in FB3. However that might not fix all problems, because Firebird also needs access to some of its lock files, etc in `C:\ProgramData\Firebird`, and I have heard about some problems when running non-privileged Firebird processes (but I believe that had to do with creating the initial folder). That said: Firebird is a server process: except for maybe development purposes I can't see good reasons to want to run it as an application instead of a Windows service.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Yes, I also see that it is supposed to run as a service, but, well, the option to do otherwise is still open...

Comment: @Wolf True, locally I run Firebird as an application a lot, but that is just because it is easier to switch between versions when testing Jaybird (the Firebird JDBC driver I develop). And it is entirely possible that I have missed some options to make it easier to run as application when installed in `C:\Program Files` ;)